# Anonymous function in setTimeout not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a delay between two loops of the nivo-slider.

Without the `setTimeout` everything works just fine (but without delay). So the folloing example works:

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
        lastSlide: function(){ 
                $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').stop = true;
//              setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').stop = false;
//              }, 2000);
        },
});
```

If I uncomment the setTimeout-lines the slider stops but does not start again? Any ideas why?

Update:
http://jsfiddle.net/kgYNX/

2nd update:
Tried it with a wrapping function, too. The function gets called but if I use setTimeout in the new function it stops working: http://jsfiddle.net/kgYNX/1/

Comment: could you make a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Related: That `setTimeout` code is fine, the problem lies elsewhere. Unrelated: That dangling comma at the end of the function you're assigning to `lastSlide` will screw up IE8 and earlier.

Comment: I think it could be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315904/jquery-nivo-slider-set-delay-time-for-each-slide

Comment: Could it be that "the inside of setTimeout" does not know about jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it slightly different:

```
beforeChange: function(){ 
        $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').stop = true;
        var delay = 0;
        if ($('#slider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide == $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').totalSlides - 2) {
                delay = 2000;
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
                $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').stop = false;
        }, delay);
}
```

I don't know why "totalSlides - 2", but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/kgYNX/15/

Answer (score 0):

As a variant, you may add custom option to slider vars collection to prevent stop execution on lastSlide handler when slider re-enabled by timeout:

```
lastSlide: function () {
    var dontStop = $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').dontStopOnLast;
    if (!dontStop) {
        $('#slider').data("nivoslider").stop();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#slider').data("nivoslider").start();
        }, 2000);
    }
    $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').dontStopOnLast = !dontStop;
}
```