# Change pause time of first slide in Easy Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, easyslider

I am using Easy Slider 1.5 Plugin and I was trying (although I've no idea what i did).. to change the pause time of first slide to 8000 from 4000.

I don't know how i should go about it with code. But according to my logic, I think i should try and fetch the li:first-child and then set the pause: 8000

Looking for help about the same!

Update -

I have this so far -

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider").easySlider({
            auto: true,
            continuous: true    
        });
        $("#firstSlider").easySlider({
            pause: 15000    
        });
    }); 

<div id="slider">
        <ul>                
            <li id="firstSlider"><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/30"><img src="../../images/flash-image.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/7"><img src="../../images/flash-image2.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/25"><img src="images/03.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/26"><img src="images/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/27"><img src="images/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>          
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: except of pause time, does it works correctly?

Comment: first slide does not pause for 15 second, it pauses only for 4 second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
Used EasySlider 1.7.
And modified some code to get the desired result.

Here's how i did it - (my blog post)
http://thecuriousengineer.org/how-to-change-the-pause-time-of-first-slide-in-easyslider/

Answer (score 0):

### It seems that Easy Slider can't set option to separately slide.

Here is the source code, it did not provide method to modify separate slide.
If You want to use this plug-in to do what you want, you must to rewrite some code to modify source code.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.easySlider = function(options){

    // default configuration properties
    var defaults = {            
        prevId:         'prevBtn',
        prevText:       'Previous',
        nextId:         'nextBtn',  
        nextText:       'Next',
        controlsShow:   true,
        controlsBefore: '',
        controlsAfter:  '', 
        controlsFade:   true,
        firstId:        'firstBtn',
        firstText:      'First',
        firstShow:      false,
        lastId:         'lastBtn',  
        lastText:       'Last',
        lastShow:       false,              
        vertical:       false,
        speed:          800,
        auto:           false,
        pause:          4000,
        continuous:     false,
        hoverpause:     false
    }; 

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  

    this.each(function() {  
        var obj = $(this);              
        var s = $("li", obj).length;
        var w = $("li", obj).width(); 
        var h = $("li", obj).height(); 
        obj.width(w); 
        obj.height(h); 
        obj.css("overflow","hidden");
        var ts = s-1;
        var t = 0;
        $("ul", obj).css('width',s*w);          
        if(!options.vertical) $("li", obj).css('float','left');

        if(options.controlsShow){
            var html = options.controlsBefore;
            if(options.firstShow) html += '<span id="'+ options.firstId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.firstText +'</a></span>';
            html += ' <span id="'+ options.prevId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.prevText +'</a></span>';
            html += ' <span id="'+ options.nextId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.nextText +'</a></span>';
            if(options.lastShow) html += ' <span id="'+ options.lastId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.lastText +'</a></span>';
            html += options.controlsAfter;                      
            $(obj).after(html);                                     
        };

        $("a","#"+options.nextId).click(function(){     
            animate("next",true);
        });
        $("a","#"+options.prevId).click(function(){     
            animate("prev",true);               
        }); 
        $("a","#"+options.firstId).click(function(){        
            animate("first",true);
        });             
        $("a","#"+options.lastId).click(function(){     
            animate("last",true);               
        });     

        function animate(dir,clicked){
            var ot = t;             
            switch(dir){
                case "next":
                    t = (ot>=ts) ? (options.continuous ? 0 : ts) : t+1;                     
                    break; 
                case "prev":
                    t = (t<=0) ? (options.continuous ? ts : 0) : t-1;
                    break; 
                case "first":
                    t = 0;
                    break; 
                case "last":
                    t = ts;
                    break; 
                default:
                    break; 
            };  

            var diff = Math.abs(ot-t);
            var speed = diff*options.speed;                     
            if(!options.vertical) {
                p = (t*w*-1);
                $("ul",obj).animate(
                    { marginLeft: p }, 
                    speed
                );              
            } else {
                p = (t*h*-1);
                $("ul",obj).animate(
                    { marginTop: p }, 
                    speed
                );                  
            };

            if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){                    
                if(t==ts){
                    $("a","#"+options.nextId).hide();
                    $("a","#"+options.lastId).hide();
                } else {
                    $("a","#"+options.nextId).show();
                    $("a","#"+options.lastId).show();                   
                };
                if(t==0){
                    $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
                    $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();
                } else {
                    $("a","#"+options.prevId).show();
                    $("a","#"+options.firstId).show();
                };                  
            };              

            //if(clicked || (options.auto && options.pauseOnHover ) clearTimeout(timeout);
            if(options.auto && dir=="next" && !clicked){;
                timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    animate("next",false);
                },diff*options.speed+options.pause);
            };

        };
        // init
        var timeout;
        if(options.auto){;
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                animate("next",false);
            },options.pause);
        };      
        if(options.hoverpause && options.auto){
            $(this).mouseover(function(){
                clearTimeout(timeout);                  
            }).mouseout(function(){
                animate("next",false);                  
            })
        }
        if(!options.continuous && options.controlsFade){                    
            $("a","#"+options.prevId).hide();
            $("a","#"+options.firstId).hide();              
        };              

    });

};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: how is that possible? there must be some way, isn't it?

Comment: I find out some easy slide example. But it only set option by only .easyslide on whole silder

Comment: I update my answer. I think using another plug-in will be a choice.

Comment: which plugin would you suggest?

Comment: hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315904/jquery-nivo-slider-set-delay-time-for-each-slide

Comment: Thanks Chen. I solved the problem, check below. I shared my approach.